# Does a programmer have to creates meta tags? I'm the end user (not a programmer)

Tags: meta

I didn't create our website but it's been set up for me and I just use the CMS that was created for me.

Now, I'm being alerted by all kinds of website graders that I need meta tags created. I know how to do alt image tags, and the SEO section of my craft CMS has a section for `SEO TITLE, SEO DESCRIPTION, and SEO KEYWORD` but no where does it give me a place for meta tags...and if it did, I wouldn't know how to create one.

Do I have to have the programmer who set up my site do it?

Answer (score 3):

Metadata is an important part of a website. If you are getting poor scores from website graders and don't see any place on your site to add that information it likely wasn't implemented by the team that built your site.

It's good you've noticed this and it's worth taking the time to set up a way to manage the metadata on your site. The best way to do this in a comprehensive and maintainable way is with an SEO plugin. Once you have things setup, you should no longer need the assistance of a programmer to manage the majority of your SEO needs.

For Craft, at this point in time, there are two good SEO options that are very comprehensive in the types of metadata they manage:

- [Sprout SEO](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/seo)
- [SEOmatic](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic)

My firm is behind Sprout SEO, so my preference is with it, but SEOmatic is made by a respectable developer who I would recommend as well so it's really a matter of your preference on which one works best for you.

With either plugin, once you have it setup, you can focus on your content and the SEO plugins will worry about generating and outputting the metadata you need on your pages. If you decide to refine or grow your SEO strategy, both plugins also have ways to give you additional control over customizing the metadata further, but that's probably something that can be left for another time in your case.

Leveraging a plugin, it will likely take a developer 2-4 hours to implement a good SEO baseline on your site. For a custom or more advanced implementation, additional planning and implementation will be required.

*Please take this estimate with a grain of salt as every custom website is unique and if your original developer didn't set up any metadata that could be a signal that the rest of the project also has some non-standard things in the setup that would take the next developer more time to figure out. If you have a large site or advanced content, it can also take longer to customize metadata for special considerations, specialized content types, or your particular goals.*

Comment: I think it'll take a lot more than 2-4 hours for a custom-grown SEO solution, if it's going to be comprehensive. Using plugins for this is typically a really good idea.

Comment: I've updated the comment to clarify that the blind 2-4 hour estimate refers to using a plugin and doesn't attempt to address custom or advanced use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will most probably need a programmer if meta tags do not exist in generated html.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your programmer forgot to include it. Out of the box there are no settings for `Meta` or `Seo` information in Craft so if you have a section for it, someone has probably created it in order to include it in your templates (unless you did it yourself?)

Did you install any plugins or did someone else create any plugins for that? Like I said maybe the team forgot it.

But in general yes: you actually need a little bit knowledge to include meta tags to your page. You don't really need to be a programmer since it's just a little bit copy pasting with Twig but you have to have access to your template files.

The following is just an example so you can't use it - it's just an example how the the thing you need to include could eventually looks like

```
{% if seoKeywords is defined %}
    <meta name="keywords" lang="{{ craft.locale }}" content="{{ seoKeywords }}"/>
{% else %}
    {% set seoKeywords = secondredSEO.getKeywords(_context) %}
    {% if seoKeywords %}
        <meta name="keywords" lang="{{ craft.locale }}" content="{{ seoKeywords }}"/>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

{% if seoDescription is defined %}
    <meta name="description" content="{{ seoDescription }}"/>
{% else %}
    {% set seoDescription = secondredSEO.getDescription(_context) %}
    {% if seoDescription %}
        <meta name="description" content="{{ seoDescription }}"/>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

If you feel confident enough to do it yourself we can help you. Just explain us the structure of your seo section and we can provide the code you have to paste into your layout.